# How to use multiple pipes to communicate the current process with a queue of processes?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

this may be trivial to some of you more experienced programmers but I'm stuck here with no output whatsoever after pipelining (or thinking to do so) more than one program.

The problem requires the father process to start feeding data through a pipe to a first of its childs which would do the same sequentially to a list of processes in the following manner:

```
Father -> 1st Child -> 2nd -> 3rd -> ... -> stdout.
```

All processes are childs of the `Father`.

Right now I have what I thought working code, but it actually stops working as soon as there is more than one program in the queue, and after looking and recoding several times I'm not able to get it to work properly.

This is what I'm working with, minus the error checking code:

```
int pipes[proc_number][2], i = 0;
for (; i < proc_number; ++i) {
    pipe(pipes[i]);
}

int current = 0;
bool first = true, last = false;
while (current != proc_number) {
    last = current == proc_number - 1;
    int pid = fork();
    // Child code:
    if (pid == 0) {
        // We always need to pipe stdin:
        dup2(pipes[current][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        // But only the last one doesn't need to pipe stdout:
        if (!last) {
            dup2(pipes[current + 1][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        // Close the array of pipes:
        for (i = 0; i < proc_number; ++i) {
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            close(pipes[i][1]);
        }
        // Exec the process:
        execlp(proc[current], proc[current], NULL);
        exit(5);
    // Father code:
    } else if (pid > 0){
        // The father process needs to pipe its output to the first child only:
        if (first) {
            dup2(pipes[current][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
    // Fork didn't work:
    } else {
        exit(6);
    }
    // Not first child anymore:
    first = false;
    // Advance to next:
    ++current;
}
// Finally close all pipes in the father process:
for (i = 0; i < proc_number; ++i) {
    close(pipes[i][0]);
    close(pipes[i][1]);
}
```

Does anybody have a clue on what is going on here? It works alright as long as there's only one child. If there are more, the processes are waiting on a pipe...

Graphically, what I wanted to accomplish was something like this (assuming 2 children):

```
Pipe0: 1st child input O====O father output
Pipe1: 2nd child input O====O 1st child out

        2nd child output unredirected, ends up in stdout.
```